It's pink only in Scene World Lighting not in Scene Lights
On Cycles CPU Mac / No image file texture just materials. How can this be fixed?



When you have an Environment Texture in your world settings without any HDRI or other image in it, Blender indicates the missing image with a purple color. But since you don't show us the setup of your Scene World, this is just blind guessing.

@GordonBrinkmann I can definitely show the setup.

Well, as I said, the Environment Texture node is empty, you did not choose any image, so it is pink. Your setup makes the camera see white, but the scene is lit by the empty texture node, resulting in everything being pink.

@GordonBrinkmann adding an HDRI helped, Thank you so much for commenting and assisting
